# Line spacing in TextFrame in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to reduce the line spacing in an Excel text frame?  The frame size I'm using should easily accommodate 3 lines of 8 pt text, but only two show, with a lot of white space between them.  It looks like the spacing is 1.5 instead of 1.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoFGX.png)

Comment: Can you a screen shot of what you mean?

Comment: Added an image.  Click Example above.